# Why async function in App.js returns undefined at initialization

Tags: react-native

There is a async method retrieving jwt token in my react native 0.59.5 `App.js`. The method is more as a wrapper and is called right after in `App.js`:

```
....
async function getToken() {
  try {
    const result = await helper.getJwtToken();
    console.log("secure store : ", result);
    if (!result) this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in retrieve jwt token : ", err.message);
    return {};
  };      

};

//socket.io
const result = getToken();
let jwt = result.password;
console.log("jwt token in App.js : ", jwt);
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL + `?token=${jwt}`, {
  //const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    jsonp: false
  });
console.log("socket id in App.js : ", socket.id);
```

The jwt token is undefined after initialization:

```
05-20 22:47:31.660 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
05-20 22:47:31.904 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
05-20 22:47:31.905 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
05-20 22:47:43.156 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
05-20 22:47:43.206 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
05-20 22:47:43.207 23027 23027 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
05-20 22:47:43.346 23027 23096 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
05-20 22:47:43.525 23027 23096 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
05-20 22:47:43.545 23027 23096 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
05-20 22:47:43.572 23027 23096 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
05-20 22:47:43.572 23027 23096 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
05-20 22:47:43.575 23027 23101 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
05-20 22:47:43.577 23027 23101 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
05-20 22:47:43.593 23027 23101 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
05-20 22:47:49.001 23027 23100 I ReactNativeJS: 'secure store : ', ''
05-20 22:47:49.002 23027 23100 I ReactNativeJS: 'Error in retrieve jwt token : ', 'undefined is not an object (evaluating \'this.props.navigation\')'
 05-20 22:47:49.049 23027 23100 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket id in App.js : ', undefined
```

But when bringing up the initial component after initialization , the similar code (retrieving jwt token) works fine and jwt token stored is retrieved successfully and so is socket.io. How to make this `async getToken` code working in `App.js` for initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you do not wait for the `getToken()` function to finalize.

Try using **await** when invoking `getToken()`, like this:

```
//socket.io
const result = await getToken();
let jwt = result.password;
console.log("jwt token in App.js : ", jwt);
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL + `?token=${jwt}`, {
  //const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    jsonp: false
  });
console.log("socket id in App.js : ", socket.id);
```

Comment: Can't use `await` outside of async function. That is why the await is wrapped inside.